# CORS error while making place API call from s3 bucket static website

Tags: cors, google-places-api

I have a static website hosted on AWS S3 bucket. My website has Google place API integartion, but I am getting CORS error while my website is trying to make request to "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete" API.

I have configured following CORS on S3 bucket -

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]
```

Is there anythng else I am missing? I also have updated CORS settings on Google API Console -

[image]

**Note :- It works if I enable CORS extension in browser**

Comment: CORS is to be configured on the server side (in your case: Google Maps' API), not on the client side (in your case: S3). You'll need to configure Google Maps' API for CORS if you can.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource—when trying to get data from a REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871637/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-whe)

Comment: @jub0bs - Thanks much for your prompt response, I have enabled CORS from google API console and hence able to make request from my localhost. But the same code is not workig on S3 bucket.

Comment: _I have enabled CORS from google API console_. Edit your question and explain how.